# How can I send a message to the github API with curl?

Tags: html, .net, curl

I am trying to modify the label color like this: [LABEL API](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/labels/)

```
curl -k -u "xx:yy" https://api.github.com/repos/xx/zz/labels -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "{'name':'Bug','color':'ff00ff'}"
```

The format looks okay to me but it returns:

```
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON"
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong with my Json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `Content-Type: application/json`.